# need help on a piece of code from PHP 5 Social Networking

Tags: php

I'm trying to get more advanced with php and I pick up the book PHP 5 Social Networking by Michael Peacock.  While the book seemed to be interesting it didn't however get to involved in the details of the code.  The function I'm trying to figure out is,

```
    public function getURLData()
{
    $urldata = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : '' ;

    $this->urlPath = $urldata;

    if( $urldata == '' )
    {
        $this->urlBits[] = '';
        $this->urlPath = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $data = explode( '/', $urldata );

        while ( !empty( $data ) && strlen( reset( $data ) ) === 0 )
        {
            //NOTES: php array_shift — Shift an element off the beginning of array
            array_shift( $data );
        }


        while ( !empty( $data ) && strlen( end( $data ) ) === 0)
        {
            array_pop($data);
        }

        $this->urlBits = $this->array_trim( $data );
    }
}
```

This a part of a larger class and the $_GET['page'] is something like this: relationships/mutual/3.  My main question is what is happening in the else section.  I think what is happening that it's removing any empty array indexes but I also question that.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  added array_trim function that is also part of the class

```
    private function array_trim( $array )
{
    while ( ! empty( $array ) && strlen( reset( $array ) ) === 0)
    {
        array_shift( $array );
    }

    while ( !empty( $array ) && strlen( end( $array ) ) === 0)
    {
        array_pop( $array );
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: You're right. Although I don't know the array_trim function but I guess it does somehow remove empty indexes that not at the beginning or the end of $data...

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Now is the hard part of why this would occur and that it needs to be handled.  Part of the .httpaccess is RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA].  So page would be populated with everything following the website.  www.mysite/relationships/mutual/3, page = relationships/mutual/3.  As I said I'm just trying to explore using classes and gain new knowledge.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public function getURLData()
{
```

Gets the 'page', this data can be obtained by $_GET from the url: for instance: http://mysite.com/?page=contact

If 'page' has been set, is assigned to $urldata, else $urldata=''

```
    $urldata = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : '' ;

    $this->urlPath = $urldata;

    if( $urldata == '' )
    {
        $this->urlBits[] = '';
        $this->urlPath = '';
    }
    else
    {
```

Now is creating an array with all the substrings from $urldata splited by '/'

```
        $data = explode( '/', $urldata );
```

If the array $data is not empty (otherwise accessing a non-existent element would raise an exception) or the lenght of the first element is equal to 0, then removes the first element from the array.

```
        while ( !empty( $data ) && strlen( reset( $data ) ) === 0 )
        {
            //NOTES: php array_shift — Shift an element off the beginning of array
            array_shift( $data );
        }
```

If the array $data is not empty (otherwise accessing a non-existent element would raise an exception) or the lenght of the last element is equal to 0, then removes the last element from the array.

```
        while ( !empty( $data ) && strlen( end( $data ) ) === 0)
        {
            array_pop($data);
        }
```

array_trim is a custom function, not sure what does but probably will do some kind of trimming too

```
        $this->urlBits = $this->array_trim( $data );
    }
```

}

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking it was doing but I started to question to what would happen if there were empty elements in the middle.  As mentioned above, I'll have try to figure out when this or how this would occur.